# « Rapporter un accident » ou « Rapporter qu’il y a un un accident »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Contexte:

> Le journal télévisé de TVYA a rapporté un accident majeur sur l’autoroute 20 à la hauteur de St-Léonard d’Aston impliquant deux voitures et un poids lourd.

> Le journal télévisé de TVYA a rapporté qu’il y a eu un accident majeur sur l’autoroute 20 à la hauteur de St-Léonard d’Aston impliquant deux voitures et un poids lourd.

Edit** (Autre possibilité qui me vient à l’esprit)

> Le journal télévisé de TVYA a rapporté qu’un accident majeur a eu lieu sur l’autoroute 20 à la hauteur de St-Léonard d’Aston impliquant deux voitures et un poids lourd.

D’autres énonciations à proposer? Peut-on se passer du verbe « rapporter » et employer plutôt « dire »? Est-ce qu’il serait préférable de penser différemment la phrase et d’écrire quelque chose du genre « Selon le journal télévisé de TVYA il y aurait…», « Selon le journal télévisé de TVYA un accident se serait produit… »?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrairement à ce que j’indiquais initialement, *rapporter* semble encore bien utilisé en France dans la presse (voir les occurrences de "a rapporté un accident" sur Google par exemple qui renvoie pas mal de résultats de presse régionale notamment), cependant, pour moi, les autres formulations suivantes seraient plus naturelles (au moins à l'oral) :

- La chaine de télévision TVYA a signalé un accident (...).
- On nous informe qu'un accident a eu lieu (...) selon la chaine TVYA.
- D'après (les informations de) TVYA, un accident aurait eu lieu/se serait produit (...).

Le verbe rapporter a aussi l'inconvénient d'avoir d'autres sens : *dénoncer un camarade* (pour un enfant), ou *rapporter un objet à quelqu'un*.
Il est cependant particulièrement adapté pour parler de faits *rapportés* par des témoins, ex:

- "Des témoins ont rapporté avoir vu des gens rôder aux abords de (...)"

Answer (score 2):

Le journal télévisé a fait mention d’un accident / a mentionné un accident / a signalé un accident / a indiqué qu’un accident a eu lieu / a relaté un accident / a annoncé un accident / a annoncé qu’un accident s’est produit / a notifié un accident / nous a informés qu’un accident s’est produit / nous a avertis d’un accident…